# SQL - Advanced "forensic" queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find out which one of the customers has purchased the largest total amount of items, with no date range

These are the columns I have:

```
customers.customerid
orders.orderid
orderdetails.productid
orderdetails.quantity
```

But I'm stuck here:

- Start with customerid
- Pull the orderid's from the customerid (using a join I assume)
- Pull the quantity and individual productid's (another join? lol)

select * from orders returns 196 records.

select distinct customerid from orders returns 74 records, so that means 74 'distinct' customers placed orders

How to complete this?

Comment: When presenting a question like this, it helps to say "Here is the table layout I am dealing with" and "Here is the kind of response I expect to get." Even though we know of the Northwind database, we don't memorize the structure.

Comment: Will post a revised version at the bottom!

Answer (score 0):

First, find out how many items each customer ordered. To do that, you have to join the order detail and orders table:

```
select o.customerid, sum(od.quantity) as nbr_items
from orderdetail od
  inner join orders o
    on o.orderid = od.orderid
group by o.customerid
```

But if you need the customer name as well, which is fairly likely, you would have to join the customer table, too:

```
select o.customerid, sum(od.quantity) as nbr_items
from orderdetail od
  inner join orders o
    on o.orderid = od.orderid
  inner join customer c
    on c.customerid = o.customerid
group by o.customerid
```

But of course, you asked specifically for the customer with the MOST TOTAL AMOUNT of items, so sort descending by that total:

```
select o.customerid, sum(od.quantity) as nbr_items
from orderdetail od
  inner join orders o
    on o.orderid = od.orderid
  inner join customer c
    on c.customerid = o.customerid
group by o.customerid
order by 2 DESC
```

And use the TOP N function to get the first one only:

```
select top 1 o.customerid, sum(od.quantity) as nbr_items
from orderdetail od
  inner join orders o
    on o.orderid = od.orderid
  inner join customer c
    on c.customerid = o.customerid
group by o.customerid
order by 2 DESC
```